# Scatterplot with ugly margins when using log scale

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a somewhat "weird" two-dimensional distribution (not normal with some uniform values, but it kinda looks like this.. this is just a minimal reproducible example), and want to log-transform the values and plot them.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(0,200),rnorm(800, 4.8)), y = c(rnorm(800, 3.2),rep(0,200)))
```

Without the log transformation, the scatterplot (incl. rug plot which I need) works (quite) well, apart from a marginally narrower rug plot on the x axis:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +  geom_rug(alpha = I(0.5)) + theme_minimal()
p
```

[image]

When plotting the same with a log10-transform though, the points at the margin (at x = 0 and y = 0, respectively) are plotted outside the rug plot or just on the axis (with other data, and only one half side of a point is visible).

```
p + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

How can I "rescale" the axes so that all the points are contained fully within the grid and the rug plots are unaffected, as in the first example?

Comment: Values smaller than zero are not shown because of the logarithmic transformation (=NaN), that's why it looks "truncated" at zero.

Comment: reproducible example please?

Comment: This IS a reproducible example, or where do you face problems?

Comment: @JT85 There are indeed zeros in the distribution (not negative values, this is just the case here). Is there a way to remove the NaN values after they are created and before they are plotted? Or do I have to add a small margin, of let's say, 10e-5 to the dataset? This is not desirable, of course, because I have many different value ranges for different variables.

Comment: I just saw that the NAs are actually removed, as the output from geom_point tells me: "3: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point)".. but still, this truncated view? I am confused.

Comment: I don't think that it will work because the axis themselves are truncated at zero, so independent of your data.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want

```
p + scale_x_log10(oob=squish_infinite) + scale_y_log10(oob=squish_infinite)
```

I don't really know what you expect to happen for those values that can be negative or infinite, but one general advice when transformations don't do what you want is to perform them outside of ggplot2. Something like this might be useful,

```
library(plyr) 
df2 <- colwise(log10)(df) # log transform columns
df2 <- colwise(squish_infinite)(df2) # do something with infinites

p %+% df2 # plot the transformed data
```